# Используется ли скрипт в сцене?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Использую Unity2d.
Подскажите, как узнать используется ли скрипт в сцене или нет? На сцене объект использовал скрипт S1. Объект стал ненужным и был удалён. Но скрипт S1 мог быть присвоен какому-то другому объекту. И если скрипт удалить из ассетов, то может где-то появится ошибка. Поэтому хочу быть уверенным, что скрипт не используется. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

В контекстном меню, все объекты отобразятся в иерархии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]